# ModifiedContent Constrained To Certain Type of View

Tags: swiftui

Consider this contrived code:

```
struct ModifiedContentView<Content: View>: View {
    
    let content: Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        content
            .font(.largeTitle)
    }
}
```

This allows me to use this call to return a `Text` view where the text has a font of `.largeTitle`. I would use it like this:

```
    ModifiedContentView() {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
```

However, this compiles and runs, it just doesn't do anything to modify the view:

```
    ModifiedContentView() {
        Circle()
    }
```

My question is simple, how do I constrain the type to be a `Text` view, or better, a view that `.font()` actually modifies? I would like an error thrown by the compiler if I try to modify the `Circle()`.

Comment: You want font modifier put effect on circle? AFAIK Apple API do not support it, may you work on a custom code for that

Comment: No, the opposite. I want the compiler to give me an error that I CAN'T put a font modifier on a circle. My problem is that using the `Circle()` is valid code that doesn't actually work. I want the compiler to complain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way for you:

If you try Circle, it give this error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Circle' to closure result type 'Text'

```
struct ModifiedContentView<Content: View>: View  {
    
    let content: () -> Content
    
    init(content: @escaping () -> Content) where Content == Text {
        self.content = content
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        content()
            .font(.largeTitle)
    }
}
```

### But I recommend this way for you:

```
extension Text {
    
    var largeTitle: some View {
        return self
            .font(.largeTitle)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I had tried to put the `Content == Text` in the struct declaration. I didn't think of trying it in the `init()`.

Comment: See the second way, that is what you need.

Comment: As to the recommendation, I am actually doing something different and that won't work. I was just trying to figure out the constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Well `font` applies its effect to the environment, not just the current view. So you may pass in a `VStack` containing `Text`, and the `Text` font will still change.

However, if you do want to only allow `Text`, simply remove the `Content` generic and replace it with `Text`:

```
struct ModifiedContentView: View {
    let content: () -> Text

    init(content: @escaping () -> Text) {
        self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {
        content()
            .font(.largeTitle)
    }
}
```

I also made the content load lazily.

Comment: It was a contrived example. I am actually working on an animation for `Text` only.

Comment: @Yrb I'm not sure what you mean by that / how it changes your question

Comment: @George: Returning just Text like you answered is not good idea in general, because if OP want put some more modifier like frame or color or opacity your struct cannot return a Text and makes error, because the content is got modified to `some View`.

Comment: @swiftPunk If you are talking about the content you pass in - it makes no difference between mine and your examples. Adding a `frame` modifier etc no longer makes it a `Text` view. If you mean by the `body`: 1) Doesn't matter what view this returns; 2) Either way `body` is still of type `Text`. Do explain again how this is wrong compared to constraining `Content` to `Text` in your example. I would say back yours is worse because even though content contains a `Text`, yours doesn't explicitly say that even though it is.

Comment: @George: Oh yeah, you are importing Text not exporting, my bad.  Text Importer  I thought you are returning.

Comment: @George: You said: "I also made the content load lazily." you mean bout: `@escaping`?

Comment: @swiftPunk I set the content as a closure, so the view content doesn't get created on `init` - in case it gets `init`ed multiple times. It only gets created when the `body` is recomputed. `@escaping` just lets the `content` closure stay around for long than the lifetime of the `init`

Comment: @George: Very good idea! You done good job there like my answer. We both used same way, but you explained it. 

Answer (score 0):

> or better, a view that .font() actually modifies?

The `View` has extension with `.font` modifier, so **any view can be modified with font**, even if it itself does not anything with font, because the applied font can be propagated to subviews, like in below example:

```
 ModifiedContentView() {
      Circle()
        .overlay(Text("Hello, World!")
            .foregroundColor(.white))
 }
```

which gives, as expected,

[image: demo]

Comment: It was a contrived example. I am actually working on an animation for `Text` only. I don't want to be able to put anything else into it.

Comment: @Asperi: The OP wants limits input content, and Text are just welcome.